# Two stores but never a sale !...Would you still recognize me?

Tags: riddle, wordplay, knowledge

My job is to stand by the doctrines of good,
And yet they call me a racist, they actually should
So, How many elements are there in the set ?
You could even link me to a circle, I bet.
Need to swing the ball ? Well, call me, won't you ?
And then you'd realize that I'm a superhero too.
I always like joining the opposites, as I may...
Well, cause "Opposites attract" is what they say.

> I'll appreciate it all the more if all the clues are well explained.

A NEW HINT, so that solving this would be a bit easier:

> The name of a Cricketer is there, but there's another board game involved.

Comment: I have a feeling the answer is the + symbol, but I dont have time to verify the lines that I don't immediately get

Comment: Well, @LukeBickell, it I'm sorry,but it isn't.

Answer (score 3):

I have a feeling this is missing something, but I want to give this a shot.  This is my first answer on PSE so feel free to let me know if there is anything wrong with my formatting or answer.

**My answer**:

> A magnet

My job is to stand by the doctrines of good

> Magnets are used in a compass.  A *moral compass* is meant to point in the direction of what is good.

And yet they call me a racist, they actually should

> Could this be a reference to the polarity of a magnet, that there is a positive and negative pole?  Magnets can both attract and repel.

So, How many elements are there in the set ?

> A magnet attracts iron, one of the elements in the periodic table.

You could even link me to a circle, I bet.

> Another reference to a compass, perhaps?

Need to swing the ball ? Well, call me, won't you ?

> This one is tough, I assume it has something to do with the magnet pulling the ball in a given direction?  I'm stretching here.  I also don't know much about cricket, so the hint in the question about a cricketer might be related to this clue, but I don't quite know the reference.

And then you'd realize that I'm a superhero too.

> **Magneto** is a superhero in the X-Men series.

I always like joining the opposites, as I may...

> This part seems self explanatory, opposite poles of a magnet are attracted to each other.

Well, cause "Opposites attract" is what they say.

> This explanation is similar to the last line.

Comment: Well, nice try but not what I was looking for, there'll be concrete explanations to all clues, yeah cricket and ball part is where you fall short.
But here's an upvote ! :)

Answer (score 2):

I am fairly sure this is the answer. But, I am stuck a little bit:

> BATMAN.

My job is to stand by the doctrines of good

> Batman in the DC Comics stands for all that is good.

And yet they call me a racist, they actually should

> Not quite sure, maybe this has something to do with it being a vigilante?

So, How many elements are there in the set ?

> 

You could even link me to a circle, I bet.

> Not completely sure. Maybe this has something to do with Bat being a sports item?

Need to swing the ball ? Well, call me, won't you ?

> A bat is very useful to swing the ball away.

And then you'd realize that I'm a superhero too.

> Batman is a superhero after all.

I always like joining the opposites, as I may...

> I think this is somehow related to Batman vs Superman where batman joins forces with Superman?

Well, cause "Opposites attract" is what they say.

> And this maybe talks about Batman's links with Catwoman? Because they are opposites?

Comment: Well, Nice try of course...but NO. That's not what I was looking for...and interestingly, the clues that you weren't sure about ( set , circle, 
 opposites ) call for the difference. Think a bit more. :) But definitely a upovte for trying :)

You couldn't justify the title either, mate. :)

Comment: @SwarnabjaBhaumik Yeah, that title thing kept bugging me. Well, I'll keep trying nonetheless

Comment: The title is exclusively wordplay. @Sid